# Hash not passing properly between functions

Tags: perl

I set up a user hash in a function with the following,

```
push @{$profile{$index}{$infoName}}, $information
```

and print it using `print Dumper(\%profile); index++;` in the function it was set up it prints each of indexes

```
`$VAR1 = { '374' => { 'degree' => [ 'CS' ], 'birthdate' => [ '1973/12/13' ], 'gender' => [ 'M' ],...}

$VAR1 = { '375' => { 'degree' => [ 'CS' ], 'birthdate' => [ '1933/02/03' ], 'gender' => [ 'F' ],...}`
```

when i try to access this within another function's foreach loop using `print "${$profile{$currIndex}{'gender'}}";` i get odd behaviour where the print returns an empty string and get some random numbers appear in the hash: `'$VAR1 = { '4' => {}, '1' => {}, '3' => {}, '2' => {}, '378' => { 'birthdate' => [ '1961/03/29' ], 'gender' => ['F'],..}`

How can i properly access the gender feild from within a loop?

Comment: Why would accessing the hash inside a loop be different from outside a loop? Somewhere in the code you are inadvertently adding those "random numbers", and you need to show your code for us to know where. Make a [sscce](http://www.sscce.org) and add it to your question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, birthdate and gender seems to be single values, why use an array for them?

Comment: @TLP okay it was adding the values elsewhere which i got rid of, this print statement still does not work though `print "${$profile{$currIndex}{'gender'}}'";`

Comment: If you add `use strict; use warnings;` it will tell you. You should never write Perl code without them. If you do as I suggested above and use a scalar instead of an array your code works fine.

Comment: I have warnings on but i can't turn on strict now as i have too many errors with it

Comment: Just declare your variables in the smallest possible scope with `my` and you'll be fine, e.g. `my $foo;`. You are dereferencing an array, so you need to use array syntax. Like I said, the better option is to not use an array, since `gender` can't very well be more than one value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> push @{$profile{$index}{$infoName}}, $information;
>
> print "${$profile{$currIndex}{'gender'}}";

I'm not even sure what the second line actually does. On my Ubuntu, perl produces an error: not a scalar reference.

What you want is, to print all array elements:

```
print "@{$profile{$currIndex}{'gender'}}\n";
```

or, to print the first:

```
print $profile{$currIndex}->{'gender'}->[0], "\n";
```

The leaf element is an array references and has to be dereferenced as such.

I'm not sure why you use there array references. In your sample data there are no multiple elements in the arrays. Probably you wanted to write simply this? -

```
$profile{$index}{$infoName} = $information;
...
print "$profile{$currIndex}{'gender'}\n";
```